# How to pass the different link values in url using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I am using laravel framework and building the system where user inputs criteria and gets all data from the database which matches their search criteria in the table. There is the link named "request" in the resulted table in each rows of data. User clicks the request link to make the request for desire items. The request link passes the ids of the particular items into the backend and update to the table column in database. At present, page has to reload every time to make the request which is quite annoying. So, Can i pass ids dynamically with link to my backend without refreshing the page using ajax?

Here is my View

```
  <div class='container' style="margin-top:50px">
        <div class="row">
    
      

      <div class="input-group" style="margin:20px">
        <form >
          <table style="float:right">
            <th>
                <div class="form-outline">
                    <input type="search" id="form1" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" /></th>                        
                      <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" >
                      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </button></th>
          
  </form>
</div>


      <div class="table-responsive">

        <table class="table custom-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">
                <label class="control control--checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="js-check-all"/>
                  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                </label>
              </th>
              <th scope="col" >S.N</th>
              <th scope="col">LC NO</th>
              <th scope="col">Applicant</th>
              <th scope="col">Doc Value</th>
              <th scope="col">Doc Received date</th>
              <th scope="col">LC Type</th>
              <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php $number = 1;?>
            @foreach($datas as $items)
              
            <tr>
              <th scope="row" style="padding:20px">
                <label class="control control--checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox"/>
                  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                </label>
              </th>
              <td>{{$number}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->lc_no}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->applicant}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->doc_value}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->rec_date}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->sight_usance}}</td>
              <td><a href="maturity_reqController/{{$items->id}}">Request</a></td>
              <td><a href="/hold_req/{{$items->id}}">Hold</a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php $number++; ?>
            @endforeach
         
            
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>


    </div>

  </div>
```

Here is my Controller

```
function maturity_reqController($id){
    $forset = new Settlement();
    $forset->org_document_id = $id;
    $forset->save();

 $data = Doc::find($id);
 $data->status = "Maturity Requested";
 $data->save();
 return redirect('maturity_settlement');


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change link like below

```
<td><a href="#" data-id="{{$items->id}}" class="sendRequest">Request</a></td>
```

and in javascript

```
<script>
$('.sendRequest').on('click',function(){
    
    var id=$(this).attr('data-id')
    $.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: "maturity_reqController/"+id,

  success: function(response)
  {
     alert(response);
  }
});

})

</script>
```

Comment: It worked but...i need to hide it from the list when it is updated...

Comment: then you need yto use jquery to hide based on row you selected